# Como fazer o sistema de login e entrada em um perfil de um usuario?

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Tenho meu sistema de cadastro de usuário e o de *login* no qual um comando busca os registros de *login* e deve retornar a entrada ao respectivo perfil do usuário. Nessa parte que fiquei sem rumo. Pesquisei e não achei artigos nem *posts* sobre o assunto. Alguém aqui teria alguma dica sobre o que eu devo estudar para conseguir fazer isso? (no caso fazer o usuário ser redirecionado para sua conta após o *login*).

Comment: Era bom você colocar o código que você ja tem, para que nós pudéssemos ajudar com suas dúvidas. Mas na internet você encontra uma série de tutorias e video aulas de como fazer. Aqui vai um:http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-sistema-de-cadastro-e-login-com-php-e-mysql/37213 .

Comment: obrigado, mais no caso esse sistema de login mostrado nesse site é seguro ?

Comment: Ele é um sistema bem simples, inclusive usa o `mysql`, que foi descontinuado nas novas versões do php e agora usa-se o `mysqli`. Mas acredito que para você que esta começando é bom começar por esses sistemas simples para entender a logica, e a partir dai, ir avançando.

Comment: sim obrigado, inclusive posso editar o código editar o codigo e por em mysqli que já ajudaria a se acostumar bastante.

Comment: Sim. mas para ter uma segurança maior, eu recomendo o prepared statement, junto com validações de email, criptografia e ai vai...

Comment: Na pergunta linkada acima tem várias respostas, com várias considerações diferentes. Use como ponto de partida para suas pesquisas e testes. Lembre-se de ver outras postagens sobre o assunto pesquisando por `Login PHP` na busca do site. E na margem direita da página, tem uma lista de coisas relacionadas também.